# Trouble Figuring out if JSON is installed or not

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

I have a php file in which i believe this line

```
 sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
```

is failing because values from my select (from eariler in the program) are not getting passed back to my app ( i checked connection and user and it is all correct ).

I am using php version 5.3.10 and it says nothing about JSON in the config i compared my phpinfo with an online server where this works and in the phpinfo() i see  JSON support=enabled, JSON version=1.2.1. Which had me thinking maybe this will work if JSOn is installed. However I was told that JSON automatically comes with php version 5+. I would like to know if that is true or if this may be failing because JSON is not enabled on my localhost server. thank you

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser("http://www.myhost.co.nf/firearm/", this);

        parser.setPostData(requestParams.toString().getBytes());
        parser.setRequestType(true);
        parser.start();
    }

    public void onResponse(String data, int code) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Vector firearmInfo = jasonParser.parseFirearmResponse(data);
        if(firearmInfo.size() > 0 ){
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    removeLoader();
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new FirearmSearchResultScreen(firearmInfo));
                }
            });
        }else{
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    removeLoader();
                    Dialog.alert("No Results found.");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong at which point, can you clarify what happens? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: just test a single `<?php echo json_encode(array("a"=>"b")); ?>` and you will see if the encode function is working properly.

Comment: @Pekka웃 simply...I have an app, which goes to webhost...runs a select..and returns me back values...this works flawlessly on ever server i try except on a localhost server. All credentials are correct, the user is properly configure and the where clause is satisfied...but nothing...gets posted to the results array and an empty array of results is passed back to my app and i believe i am write because my program gives me an error of "no results found" (refer first message for that code)

Comment: If you'd try to run `json_encode()` on a server where it isn't installed, you'd get a fatal error. Your problem is likely to be elsewhere.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I started my quest for answers in this previous thread. my complete php code is there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214803/json-or-select-failing-when-connected-to-localhost

Comment: `<?php echo (function_exists('json_encode'))?'installed':'not installed'; ?>`

Comment: Can you try to isolate at which point the problem starts occurring exactly? Your other post contains a lot of code. Try to narrow it down and post that code only, that may get better responses.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have isolated to problem the best of my ability to when it needs to be posted. because i have tested and i am able to select. I will run this function provided by Sammitch and comment back

Comment: @Sammitch thank you. I shall run that

Comment: How are you debugging this, do you have error reporting enabled so you can see what goes wrong?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Well i made a seperate script to see what goes wrong where. So i did a connect or die script...and that passed. So i did a select or die script. That also works So whats left is JSON_encode(). Funny enough...when i comment out sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
on my working server...my program behaves the same as when i am running it on the server which i suspect has a JSON problem

Comment: I still don't understand why you don't simply activate error reporting so PHP will tell you what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have been running alot more test. If  u look at this line below. It gives me a fatal error...whenever $vehicle_no is a string like "P3" or "2k"
           $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT vehicle_no,chassis_no FROM vehicle_info WHERE vehicle_no=$vehicle_no");

        $stmt->execute();

Answer (score 7):

> As of PHP 5.2.0, the JSON extension is bundled and compiled into PHP by default.

As quoted from: http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php

So there is no need to check for JSON compatibility on modern PHP versions.

Comment: So why is the program failing on this line? Also i have read that json may be installed but not be enabled Also the phpinfo file doesnt show any information on JSON

Comment: try var_dumping result or logging result to log-file by using ```error_log(var_export($result,true));```

Answer (score 0):

Although your problem is different than the question asked and you identified it in one of your comments, you did not change the question.

This answer addresses your PROBLEM. I had the same happen to me yesterday:

Query collecting JSON data from MySQL to PHP worked on local server, but when ported to production server Online array returned empty. It turned out that the MySQL version of the production server was 5.6xx and the local server 5.7xx. That difference was the answer. MySQL started supporting JSON data in 5.7 according to [this SitePoint article](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/).

ANSWER:

- update your MySQL to 5.7+ (problem solved)

**OR**

- Retrieve JSON data as text (MySQL 5.6) and use [PHP json_decode() to either an object or an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: HEY! Why downvote an answer to a difficult problem no one else found the solution to? I hate Stack Overflow! I am out of here. It explains why 70% + of your users answer only ONE QUESTION and quit. I will contribute my sweat and tears to some OTHER forum.